# Excel Data Validation deactivates in copy

Tags: excel, validation

I have a .xlsm file named A on my Laptop.
With macros it also has data validation(simple lists) applied to some cells.
I copy this file and paste it in a network shared folder so that it is visible on PC 1. ( I saved it by the name B.).
I open the file B on my laptop, it works fine.

Now I go to the PC 1  where I had copied it, and open it on the PC.
On opening the file B, I find that the macros work fine, but the data validation is not working. Those cells don't even show arrows.

Note: My laptop has Excel 2013, and the PC has excel 2007.

I don't understand if its a version difference problem or security problem or something else.

Hope I have been clear in explaining my doubt.

Please let me know where am I going wrong.

Looking Forward,
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Solved. Named Ranges does the work.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you are experiencing, but we had a similar issue not too long back, can you check if the Objects are visible?

File > Options > Advanced > Display options for this workbook > Objects > Show > All

[image]

Comment: Thanks @AranDG, but I guess something else is wrong, because in my file all objects are visible. The "all" button is on. Thanks though!

Comment: It was a long shot, it was the first time I had seen anything like that and yours sounded similar.  Good luck in finding your solution

Comment: Odd that the named ranges failed though. Glad you found a solution

Comment: Initially I had set simple cell references for the data validation lists, when I replaced the references with named ranges, the lists successfully opened and worked fine on the PC.